# Power BI - use managed identity to get data from Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-managed-identity

I have a simple scenario where I have an Azure SQL Database and I want to use the data from the DB in a Power BI report. The DB server has only Azure AD authentication enabled. So far I managed to create and refresh the dataset by using my own credentials (authentication method: OAuth2), but I would like a more generic solution which doesn't rely on a user account.

Is it possible to enable a managed identity for the Power BI workspace and use it to connect to the Azure SQL DB and get the data? This way power BI will use the same pattern the other Azure services are using to access the DB.

If Power BI managed identity is not supported yet, what would be the best alternative to pull the data without using a user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If Power BI managed identity is not supported yet, what would be the
> best alternative to pull the data without using a user account?

AFAIK, Only Azure Stream analytics job supports Managed Identity as an authentication for Power BI.

But as a workaround you can make use of Azure Service Principal or Azure AD application to authenticate with your Power BI datasets connected to Azure SQL.

I created one Power BI group where my Azure AD Service principal and users exists.

I connected to my Azure SQL server with Powerbi like below:-

[image]

[image]

Created one PowerBi report out of Azure SQL dataset like below:-

[image]

Uploaded it to PowerBi Web :-

[image]

I have one PowerBI embed group which has Embed Demo app and users who can access Power BI like below:-

[image]

Logged into my Power BI web portal > Settings > Admin Portal > Tenant Settings

[image]

Set Allow Embed Settings Enabled :-

[image]

Allow Service Principals to use Power BI and give powerbiembedgroup access.

[image]

Provide Service Principal access to workspace or specific dataset:-

[image]

[image]

Access PowerBI via Powershell:-

Install PowerBI Powershell module -

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
```

Connect to PowerBI with SP -

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential (Get-Credential) -Tenant xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxexx-99ed-af9038592395
```

[image]

In the Username and password add the App ID and password of the Service principal.

Connected to PowerBI successfully :-

[image]

Get the workspace -

```
   Get-PowerBIWorkspace
```

**References:-**

[Embed Power BI content in an embedded analytics application with service principal and an application secret - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal?source=recommendations)

[Use Managed Identity to authenticate your Azure Stream Analytics job to Power BI output | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/powerbi-output-managed-identity)

Comment: but you are still using the user account to connect Power BI to the database